# CKEditor doesn't work correctly with React Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, ckeditor, ckeditor5-react

I'm having a hard time with material ui & CKEditor5.

The problem is, CKEditor doesn't work correctly.
When I try to use editor features like bold, italic etc. Nothing changes on the screen, however I can log all modified text in console. I've tried exact same code in codesandbox and it worked without any problem.

I've read the documentation, I did everything correctly step by step as described.

So far I have tried these and none of them worked.

- Seperated editor css and imported it.
- Put !important to override material-ui theme.
- Removed material-ui theme.

Anyone has an idea about why is this happening?

- this is how it looks like on browser  [image: This is how it looks like]
- this is how it looks like on console [image]

Answer (score 0):

install same exact package thats in the sandbox package.json I had also facing issue like your but fixing it by correcting the version issue.